# emacs, do a search, copy some text, and then return to the point of search originally?

Tags: emacs

I am doing a search backwards in the text in emacs, then I move the point around and do a modification or copy, but then can I return to the point of the search before or do I still have to search for text around that spot?

Best,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
M-x pop-to-mark-command
```

And you can also get that functionality by <kbd>C-u SPC</kbd> or <kbd>C-u C-@</kbd> (i.e. using a [prefix argument](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Command-Arguments.html) with the [`set-mark-command`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Setting-Mark.html#Setting-Mark)).

For more information on the mark ring, read [about the mark ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mark-Ring.html#Mark-Ring).  There is also a [global mark ring](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Global-Mark-Ring.html), which is basically a list of marks across buffers, which you can navigate via <kbd>C-x C-SPC</kbd>.

Comment: I think that it should have been C-u C-SPC as I saw from the fantastic links that you put up with the commands, for getting the M-x pop-to-mark-command effect in keystroke

Comment: from the links i saw that the original mark C-SPC must be pressed twice to deactivate it and put it on the ring

Answer (score 5):

I've [tweaked some elisp, point-stack](http://github.com/mattharrison/point-stack) to allow for quick forward/backward through buffers.  I've [written more on my blog](http://panela.blog-city.com/python_and_emacs_7_buffer_navigation_point_history.htm), but the basic idea is `f5` to push a location, `f6` to jump back, `f7` for forward.

Here's and animated gif showing it.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> `foo` <kbd>Enter</kbd>        *Notice that “Mark saved where search started” message?*

... edit ...

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>        *Go back to the saved mark*

If you used the mark during the “edit” part, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> again that many times. The successive marks are stored on a ring (for simple uses, what you see is a mark stack): each time the mark is set, it's pushed onto the stack, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> goes to the mark popped from the stack.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> `42` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to go back to the 42nd previous mark.

If you put `(setq set-mark-command-repeat-pop t)` in your `.emacs`, you can repeat just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to go back to successive previous marks.

Answer (score 2):

Before search use `Ctrl-space` to save your mark. Then do a seach and copy some text. Then, use `Ctrl-u-Ctrl-space` to pop back to your saved mark.

Comment: but i use the mark when doing the copying at the search point?

Comment: @Vass: you can set mark multiple times. Emacs remembers this. You can also go back to previous marks multiple times. So there's no need to worry ;-)

Comment: It's not necessary to explicitly save your mark before searching, this is so common that it's done by default. You may notice "Mark saved where search started" in your *Messages* buffer.